# Error message “This page does not work” in GC with VS2017

Tags: google-chrome, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2017

I work with Visual Studio 2017 V 15.9.2 and develop an asp.net core 2.2 application.
In VS2017, I have configured Google Chrome as default browser.

In the past, GC was started by starting debugging with VS2017 and have started a new GC instance (also if GC already was started).

Now, I have (abruptly) an strange problem...
Since a few days google chrome don’t start properly, if I start debugging in VS2017.
Google Chrome shows an error page (translated from German):

> This page does not work
>   If the problem persists, contact the site owner.
>   HTTP ERROR 400

If I copy the generated link (http://localhost:14300/) to another (manually started) GC instance it works.

Note:
Before the problem occurred the first time, I had a crash in the .net core application.
I already have deleted the GC cache, but maybe there are some “hidden“ entries, where GC notes crashes and prevent the page from loading (but oddly enough only if started from VS, as it runs in a manually started GC instance) ?

Comment: 400 is a bad request. The most common cause in a web browser is that the antiforgery cookie is missing or doesn't match what the server is expecting. Ensure that Chrome is allowing cookies to be set.

Comment: Thanks for your posting. I know that 400 means bad request. The problem was, that it seems as some corrupt cookies were stored what - oddly enough - only had a consequence to the start from VS2017 (see my answer).

Answer (score 0):

I have find the solution myself.
Although I have deleted the cached data with the "global function" of google chrome, it still had stored some cookies.

I followed step by step these instructions:

1. On your computer, open Chrome.
2. At the top right, click More     Settings.
3. At the bottom, click Advanced.
4. Under "Privacy and security," click Site settings.
5. Click Cookies   See all cookies and site data.
6. At the top right, search for the website's name.
7. To the right of the site, click Remove

searched the site localhost and deleted all cookies.

Although it's illogical for me (as the link with localhost has worked in a manually started browser), it works now again also by the start directly from VS2017...